# C# - Cortana voice commands to launch external application

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-universal, cortana

I am trying to integrate different files and links to  the Cortana voice commands using C#. Most of the applications are working fine when i copy those particular files in the Cortana voice command application folder but i am unable to launch an *.exe file (copied in the same folder). The usual error i am getting is *access denied* even after launching VS as admin. I am attaching the code line along with the error screenshot.

```
{"Abrir NAV", (Action)(async () => {
            StorageFile file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.exe");
            await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
        })
},
```

[Cortana Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAkfm.png)

Comment: I can translate error. It says :

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The system can not find the specified file. (Excep_FromHResult 0x80070002) '

Answer (score 0):

You could not launch executable file from your UWP app directly.

MSDN document has mentioned this point:

> This API also imposes several restrictions on what types of files it can launch. Many file types that contain executable code, for example .exe, .msi, and .js files, are blocked from launching. This restriction protects users from potentially malicious files that could modify the system. From [launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher) documentation.

According to your description, your ".exe" file was contained in your UWP project. So, you could use the [FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher) method to activate the full-trust Win32 component of an application from a Universal Windows app component in the same application package.

Please note the "full-trust" concept. You would need to declare "full-trust" for your ".exe" file in "Package.appxmanifest". For example:

```xml
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap= "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap desktop">
  <Applications>
     <Application>
     ...
      <Extensions>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="MyFiles\ConsoleApp1.exe"/>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
 </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

[image]

Then, in code, you could call this method to launch that ".exe" file.

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

Comment: Hey Xavier, I tried doing as you said but i am getting an error C00CE014, it has something to do with this line

<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="MyFiles\ConsoleApp1.exe"/>

Comment: You might miss adding other things in Package.appxmanifest. Please check if you have add `xmlns:rescap` `xmlns:desktop` `IgnorableNamespaces` and if you have put the `desktop:Extension` in right place. After that, if you still cannot locate this issue. Please upload a [mcve].

Comment: I have actually added the tags you mentioned but everytime i try to debug it, build meta and </desktop Extension: FullTrustProcess> is added to the manifest

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" 
 xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
 xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows1"
 xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" 
 xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10" 
xmlns:build="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build"
  IgnorableNamespaces="desktop">

Comment: Even after removing build xmlns it´s still creating metas.

Comment: IgnorableNamespaces would be like this `IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap desktop"`

Comment: Hello @Xavier Xie, i fixed that issue by removing Release folder form the location and the error is gone but now when i try to Debug it i get i am getting System.NotImplementedException error.

Comment: i have used the fullTrustProcess in following way

`{"Abrir NAV", (Action) (async() => {

                try
                {
                await Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();

                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("Rebuild the solution and make sure the BackgroundProcess is in your AppX folder");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }) }, `

Comment: I have a small doubt , i don't have my .EXE file in my UWP folder but in my local drive. Do you think that could be the problem that i am unable to launch it?

Comment: @gopaljoshi Yeah, please check my above reply carefully. Your ".exe" file needs to be contained in your UWP project. You cannot launch executable file from outside of your UWP app container.

Comment: Yes , i get that and i moved the ".exe" file to my UWP folder but it doesn´t work still. But is there no other way to launch and application directly from it´s parent folder ?

Comment: What did you mean about "it doesn't work still"? You cannot launch the ".exe" file, right? If so, please provide a reproducible code sample. I need to check your total project. **But is there no other way to launch and application directly from it´s parent folder ?** There's no other way.